# Test ASP.NET MVC routes using MVC Contrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, unit-testing, mvccontrib

I'm trying to set up Route mapping tests using [MVC Contrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) as described in [Test ASP.NET MVC routes using MVC Contrib](http://ubiquitous-tech.blogspot.com/2009/07/test-aspnet-mvc-routes-using-mvc.html)

The tests compile and execute, but they always fail with the message "The URL did not match any route."

I set up another test to try to get an idea of what the problem is:

```
    Public Sub TestIndexRoute()
        Dim routes = New RouteCollection
        myMvcApp.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes)
        Assert.That(routes.Count > 0)
        Assert.NotNull(routes("Default"), "Default route not found.")
        Dim routeData = RouteTestingExtensions.Route("~/Author")
        Assert.NotNull(routeData, "routeData is Nothing.")
        Assert.That(routeData.Values("controller") = "Author")
    End Sub
```

That test fails on `Assert.NotNull(routeData, "routeData is Nothing.")`, so I know that there must be some problem with the MVCContrib code that is trying to access my app's RouteCollection.

From the blog post:

> It also assumes you set your routes in the ASP.NET MVC RouteCollection object.

How do I confirm that I'm doing that? I'm using routes.MapRoute within MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes method in the Global.asax code behind. Is there something else to do to set this up properly?

**Edit:** I should probably mention that I'm new to unit testing. I've been putting off learning it for too long and this seemed like as good a place to start as any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

instead of:

```
Dim routes = New RouteCollection
myMvcApp.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(routes)
```

See [RouteTestingExtensions, line 43](http://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/source/browse/trunk/src/MVCContrib.UnitTests/TestHelper/RouteTestingExtensionsTester.cs?spec=svn769&r=769#43)

Comment: Thanks! That's the piece I was missing!